# Stop excel from converting formula to text csv

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, export-to-csv

How do I keep excel from removing my formula inserted into a csv to text?

For example in my csv I have data and have the formula `"=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1,B2))"` then I open the csv in excel and see the value of the formula. But when I save, the formula is removed and replaces it with the evaluation of the formula, i.e. `true`.

Comment: You could use [ctrl]+[back tick] to show formulas. Saving to CSV will save the formulas into the text file but they will be wrapped in quotes and you will have to convert them back to working formulas from text-that-looks-like-a-formula if you reimport the CSV to Excel.

Comment: probably easiest to do just remove the `=`. that way you just have to add that back on to evaluate as formula

Comment: @AmitKohli the problem I have with removing the =  sign is if I have tons of rows it is not easy to add it back.

Comment: You can write a macro to add them back in... would you like that code?

Comment: @AmitKohli that code would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a column of formulas that need to have an "=" added to it... so put your cursor on that column, and then run this macro:

```
Sub equalAdder()
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Value = "=" & ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend
End Sub
```

How does that work?