# Is there a way to use ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas when running a VBScript without an Excel window?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a VBScript that converts Excel sheets to CSV files. It is run in the background (i.e., without an Excel window up) by doing the following:

```
Dim oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I found that in [Saving worksheets to CSV with Excel Formulas intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491719/saving-worksheets-to-csv-with-excel-formulas-intact), the accepted answer suggests using

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = True
```

which is wonderfully simple, but throws an ObjectRequired error on 'ActiveWindow' when I run my script. The second answer is more complicated, but I imagine it would work.

[Stop excel from converting formula to text csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247242/stop-excel-from-converting-formula-to-text-csv) suggests using a macro, but I'm not sure if this would work. Also, it is not as simple as using the DisplayFormulas property.

Is there a way to make use of the DisplayFormulas property in a script without actually displaying an Excel window?

Comment: Simply tried `oExcel.DisplayFormulas = True` or `Application.DisplayFormulas = True` ?

Comment: `.ActiveWindows` is a property of Excel's application object. Under COM rules the application object is a global object to scripts running in that process. It is not global when automating from outside. In Excel VBA looks at the properties of the global object to find if that is what you meant. In VBS (or any other program outside of Excel) must specify the path - `oExcel.ActiveWindow`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/using-the-application-object-in-a-type-library

Comment: @Noodles, thank you very much! That explanation was very helpful. `oExcel.ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = True` did the trick. I'm not sure why you added the link though; it doesn't seem relevant here, as it doesn't look like it describes what you said. Why did you add it?

Comment: The link takes you into the section that *talks about the rules I summarized*. The actual page (in the middle of the section) talks about the requirements for ANY application object (Word, Adobe, Internet Explorer, etc). Nearby pages talk about the document object (called worksheets in Excel), then StdFont, StdPicture, and the other standard COM objects.

Comment: The link is to give you conceptual understanding of the model you are programming to. So the concepts are transferrable. EG `ExcelApp.Quit`, `WordApp.Quit`, `MyApp.Quit`. That there is an underlying model and commands aren't just random collections of commands but follow rules. A nearby page tells you the rules about how you should name COM objects.